# US B1/B2 Visa validity for re-use

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

tldr: I used a B1/B2 visa three years ago and want to know if I can re-use it this year, because length appears to be 10 years.

I have a B1/B2 US visa in my passport, issued `2019/9/9`. It says that the expiration date is `2029/9/4`. And `Entries` has an `M` (for `multiple` I assume.

I used the Visa in `2019`, with entry date `14 October`. However there is a date next to the entry stamp for `April 13 2020` (6 months later).
Does this date have any significance regarding me revisiting the US this year, or is it safe to use the same visa given that the apparent expiry is only in `2029`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the same visa till 2029.

The date means once you enter, you are granted 6 months to remain in US. You have to leave within that date.

Considering your circumstances, you shouldn't have any problem entering the US. You just have to have a return ticket and proof of accommodation (details of your activity if its a business related visit).

Comment: Thanks! I will be staying with my brother-in-law, so I guess I'll need a letter from him stating this, and would like to see the city while there. But I think B1/B2 also allows for some tourism.

Comment: @rewolf you don't really need a letter from your brother in law.  If the immigration officer asks where you're staying, you can just say "with my brother in law."  They don't typically need the same degree of evidence that a visa officer needs to grant the visa.

Comment: @phoog I will still include a proof of accommodation to convince Airline people. They are usually more overzealous than immigration agents. :D Just a paper with name, relationship, address and phone number worked fine for me in the past.

Comment: You don't _have to have_ a return ticket nor proof of accommodation with a B1/B2 visa.  Not for immigration nor airline personnel.